# How to catch a soft keyboard 'enter/done' press?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I would like to know when the user presses the 'enter/done/next' key on the soft keyboard without the activity knowing which edittext box the user is in. I have seen some code, but it always uses the name of the edittext box that is being edited.

The app has numerous edittext boxes, and calculations are re-run anytime any one of the values in a edittext box is changed.

Answer (score 6):

Then attach the `OnEditorActionListener` to all of them.

Comment: I've only seen this used in the definition of a new method like this for example: textEdit5.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {   if(arg1 == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION){   btnSave.requestFocus(); return true; } return false; }); Do I have to create a new method for every one of the 14 edittext boxs I have?

Comment: @Ted Betz: No. You call `setOnEditorActionListener()` on the 14 EditText widgets. Here is a sample app where I use an `OnEditorActionListener` for a custom `View` in the Honeycomb action bar: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC

Comment: @Ted Betz: You create a single `OnEditorActionListener` object and use it 14 times. The code you put in your edited comment above would create a single-use disposable `OnEditorActionListener` object. This is simply Java syntax and has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: I tried the myEditText1.setOnEditorActionListener(); to initiate each of the 14 listeners, with no luck. I appreciate the reference to your sample code, but it too uses the OnEditorAction in a single-use method. Can you give ma a sample of how I can initiate 14 listeners without duplicating '//Do Stuff' code in every listener?

Comment: @Ted Betz: "I appreciate the reference to your sample code, but it too uses the OnEditorAction in a single-use method" -- no, it does not. `onSearch` is not a method. It is an object, specifically a data member of the activity.

Comment: I see..it looks very efficient, certainly more elegant than 14 listeners. Your sample is missing the "KeyEvent event){", guess it got clipped somehow. Even so, its not catching any events when I try it. Any ideas why not?

Comment: @Ted Betz: "guess it got clipped somehow" -- actually, it's scrolled to the right. For book publication, I use two-space tabs; GitHub's Web interface uses eight-space tabs. Not pretty. "Even so, its not catching any events when I try it. Any ideas why not?" -- that particular sample will only show the `EditText` on a Honeycomb device/emulator. I have used the technique in other places (not open source). Make sure you have the `android:imeActionId` and
`android:imeOptions="actionDone"` attributes on the `EditText` in your layout file.