# Android Use Done button on Keyboard to click button

Tags: android, keyboard-events, android-softkeyboard

Ok in my app I have a field for the user to input a number. I have the field set to only accept numbers. When the user clicks on the field it brings up the keyboard. On the keyboard (on ICS) there is a done button. I would like for the done button on the keyboard to trigger the submit button i have in my application. My code is as follows.

```
package com.michaelpeerman.probability;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProbabilityActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button submit;
ProgressDialog dialog;
int increment;
Thread background;
int heads = 0;
int tails = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    submit = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.submit));
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    increment = 1;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setMessage("Flipping Coin...");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setProgress(0);
    EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
    int maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
    dialog.setMax(maximum);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){

          public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

              background.interrupt();
              TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                result.setText("heads : " + heads + "\ntails : " + tails);


          }});


    background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            heads=0;
            tails=0;
            for (int j = 0; !Thread.interrupted() && j < dialog.getMax(); j++) {
                int i = 1 + new Random().nextInt(2);
                if (i == 1)
                    heads++;
                if (i == 2)
                    tails++;
                progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    background.start();
}

Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
        if (dialog.getProgress() == dialog.getMax()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            result.setText("heads : " + heads + "\ntails : " + tails);


        }
    }

};

}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330243/how-to-catch-a-soft-keyboard-enter-done-press

Comment: That refers to the textbox updating.

Comment: What i want to do is for it too trigger a button i already have. I dont want to get rid of the button because some people may be using keyboards that dont have a done button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android detect Done key press for OnScreen Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077425/android-detect-done-key-press-for-onscreen-keyboard)

Answer (score 344, accepted):

You can use this one also (sets a special listener to be called when an action is performed on the EditText), it works both for DONE and RETURN:

```
max.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Enter pressed");
            }    
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also, showing a nice send button in the keyboard itself would make it better. Add below line in EditText xml:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSend"
android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: How can i set it to trigger the on click i already have running off of the submit button public void onClick(View view) {

Comment: You can either move all that code into single function and then call it or use [performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29)

Comment: This did not work for me when hitting a DONE button, the KeyEvent was always null.. the actionId however was set to EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE and I was able to use that instead. (This is in android 4.2.2 and does not even match the android sdk documentation at this time)

Answer (score 30):

You can try with [**`IME_ACTION_DONE`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_DONE) .

> This action performs a “done” operation for nothing to input and the
>   IME will be closed.

```
 Your_EditTextObj.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                boolean handled = false;
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                  /* Write your logic here that will be executed when user taps next button */


                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This one works perfect for me. Be careful about return TRUE. Keyboard remains displayed. If you want to hide keyboard return FALSE.

Comment: Works like gem!

Answer (score 29):

### Kotlin Solution

The base way to handle the done action in Kotlin is:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // Call your code here
        true
    }
    false
}
```

### Kotlin Extension

Use this to call `edittext.onDone {/*action*/}` in your main code. Keeps it more readable and maintainable

```
edittext.onDone { submitForm() }

fun EditText.onDone(callback: () -> Unit) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            callback.invoke()
            true
        }
        false
    }
}
```

#### Don't forget to add these options to your edittext

```
<EditText ...
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

> If you need **`inputType="textMultiLine"`** support, [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779604/974045)

Comment: This listener in fact always returns `false` (Kotlin puzzler ;)), but it is fine: we typically want keyboard to close.

Comment: @gmk57 Try adding an else to that if statement and have it contain the false. I believe you are always seeing false because the if statement sets a true, but then it flows directly to the false on the next line (outside the if).

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
max.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            //do what you want
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: When you push any button your view generates event onKey, and when keyCode matched against the right button it does something you want

Comment: button has to have focus

Answer (score 8):

Try this for Xamarin.Android (Cross Platform)

```
edittext.EditorAction += (object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs e) {
       if (e.ActionId.Equals (global::Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done)) {
           //TODO Something
       }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I copied the following code from AndroidStudio when you create a LoginActivity.
I use the ime attributes

In your layout

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/unidades" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="@string/prompt_unidades"
                    android:inputType="number" android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:enabled="true" android:focusable="true"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/cantidad"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/add"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"/>
```

In your Activity

```
editTextUnidades.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == R.id.cantidad || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                addDetalle(null);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement on key listener:

```
public class ProbabilityActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, View.OnKeyListener {
```

In onCreate:

```
max.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

...

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        //call your button method here
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to catch the keyboard enter button for doing your job which you want to done through any event like button click, you can write the below simple code for that text view

```
Edittext ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

ed.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        // Do you job here which you want to done through event
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin and Numeric keyboard**

If you are using the numeric keyboard you have to dismiss the keyboard,
it will be like:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
  if (action == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || action == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || action == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED) {
      //hide the keyboard
      val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
      //Take action
      editValue.clearFocus()
      return true
  } else {
      return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this class in your layout :

```
public class ActionEditText extends EditText
{
    public ActionEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ActionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ActionEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs)
    {
        InputConnection conn = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        outAttrs.imeOptions &= ~EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION;
        return conn;
    }
```

}

In xml:

```
<com.test.custom.ActionEditText
                android:id="@+id/postED"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="@string/msg_type_message_here"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
        //do what you want
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Commenting on your code always improves the readability of an answer...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Last Edittext .setOnEditorActionListener call this method automatic hit api**

**I was Call in LoginActivity in et_password**

```
 et_Pass.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {

                    Log.i(TAG,"Enter pressed");
                    Log.i(Check Internet," and Connect To Server");

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**Working Fine**

Answer (score 0):

And this is a Kotlin version:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
  if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
      //Put your action there
      true
  } else {
      false
  }
}
```