# Android hiding keyboard with imeoptions

Tags: android, keyboard, imeoptions, honeywell

I set imeoptions="actionDone" for my EditText in xml and everything works fine on a Medion Lifetab or Nexus 4 (on press "Enter" the softkeyboard disappears).

But I need this to work on a Honeywell Dolphin e70. On this device if I press "Enter" the next EditText gets focus. I already tried to set singleline true but didnt change the behavior.

This is the EditText I use:

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/id1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".55"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen1" />
```

Like I said, on other devices it works like intended.. Anyone got an idea for a workaround or where I can start handling this? I definetly dont want to set a keylistener to EVERY damn EditText is the application, that would totaly be an overkill..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) to hide the keyboard and [Android Use Done button on Keyboard to click button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596010/android-use-done-button-on-keyboard-to-click-button) to catch the dome button action.

Comment: this all connects with a single edittext and I know how I can do this, but the question is how to do it for every edittext without setting a listener to every single one because that would be quiet a lot..
as I said, on other devices the imeOptions="actionDone" works and hides the keyboard, just the honeywell doesnt and I want to know why